# Item address in array becomes too large and causes overflow

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Item address in array becomes too large and causes overflow

```
struct payment {
    char id[17];
    char date[10];
    int cost;
    struct payment* next = NULL;
};

int main() {
    payment* hash = (payment*) malloc(n * sizeof(payment));
    // ....
    function(hash);
}

void function(payment hash[]) {
    long long j;
    // ...
    if (hash[j].id[0] == '-')
        // ...
    }
```

(The array is of size 2087123)
I have this function but because the number j gets too large (j = 1900000), so it returns overflow error.

I tried this to solve it:

```
if(((hash + j*sizeof(payment))->id)[0] == '-')
```

But it does not give me the same values as the prior method before crashing. (which are the correct ones)

Can someone help with this? (I have been searching a lot)

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing an element that does not exist.  Check if j larger than array size before accessing the element.

```
if (j < n) {
    if(hash[j].id[0] == '-')
        ...
    }
}
else {
    ...
}
```